# Pandas excel file reading gives first column name as unnamed

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am reading xlsx file like this

```
df = pd.read_excel('cleaned_data.xlsx', header=0)
df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)
df.head()
```

[image]

Problem is column names coming as first row of data.

```
# reading data from csv file
df = pd.read_excel('cleaned_data.xlsx', header=0)
#df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)
df = df.drop(0, inplace=True)
df.head()
```

I tried this way but still not luck. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried _without_ the header? `df = pd.read_excel('cleaned_data.xlsx')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One idea is use `header=1`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('cleaned_data.xlsx', header=1)
```

Another is skip first row:

```
df = pd.read_excel('cleaned_data.xlsx', skiprows=1)
```